# Changed my bundle ID and project name in Xcode 9 and now my simulators don’t launch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, xcode9

I am prepping my app for the App Store and so i went in and changed my bundle id and project name.

However, now when I try to run my app on a simulator - the build succeeds without any errors but the simulator never appears?

Wondering if there is a setting other than picking the simulator I need to check to make sure it launches a simulator with the build.

**Update**

The fix ended up being under edit scheme >> Executable was sent to none. 
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3h6L.png)

I switched that to the name of the app and that did the trick.

Comment: Any error message is shown? If not then please delete the previous one first and then run again.

Comment: Thanks Faysal. There is no error but what should I be deleting?

Comment: Erase all content and setting of simulator and Clear Derived Data

Comment: Just reset your simulator and quit your xcode and Simulator. And open again

Comment: Sometimes caching data creates some problem to run the app.

Comment: I’ve restarted Xcode a couple times but I no longer have access to the simulator. So I can’t close and restart it, it lets me pick a simulator but when it builds it never launches or opens a simulator.

Comment: just do one thing simulator> hardware > select Erase All contents and settings option and quit simulator and quit xcode and restart it, for me its helped.

Comment: I apologize for all the rookie questions, I’m a newbie. Where do I find simulator to erase all contents

Comment: I restarted to see if that would help and am now getting the error Apple Mach-O linker Error. Linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: When you app was having the old name, in which simulator you have launched your app (For eg. Iphone 7). Open that simulator directly and then uninstall the application with old name and then try launching the current app with new name.And also make sure you have selected the correct Target.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the help. It ended up being under edit scheme >> Executable was sent to none.

I selected my app there and it fired up a simulator.